# Python, object after jumping doesn't fall down. Fix?

Tags: python

i have a program in which a square is supposed to jump, then fall down. For some reason, the square is jumping but it doesn't fall down. I'm not sure what's the issue is, i hope you could help me fix it. [jumping gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS0Pn.gif)

Here i'm displaying the window while the game is being played

```
#DISPLAY WINDOW
def draw_window(square):
    #SCREEEN
    WIN.fill(black)
    #OBJECTS
     #LINE
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, white, (0, 400), (900, 400), 10)
     
     #SQUARE
    square.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here i'm defining a square class and it's methods including jumping

```
#SQUARE
class Square():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 295
        self.vel = 10

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, red, [50, self.y, 100, 100])

    def jump(self, jumpCount):
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            self.y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.05 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jump = False
            jumpCount = 10
```

Here is the main game loop with all functions

```
def main():
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 10
    square = Square()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        #JUMPING
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if not jump and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    jump = True

        if jump:
            square.jump(jumpCount)

        draw_window(square)

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some modifications to your code:

1. In the class `Square`, draw method should pass in a `pygame.Rect` as a parameter of `pygame.draw.rect`.
2. The `jump` method of `Square` created local variable `jump` and `jump_count`, changes to these variables will not affect the variable in `main()`. So you have to return these values and update them in `main()`

Full Code:

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60

class Square():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 295
        self.vel = 10

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, red, pygame.Rect(50, self.y, 100, 100))

    def jump(self, jumpCount):
        jump = True
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            self.y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.05 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jump = False
            jumpCount = 10
        
        return jump, jumpCount

#DISPLAY WINDOW
def draw_window(square):
    #SCREEEN
    WIN.fill(black)
    #OBJECTS
     #LINE
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, white, (0, 400), (900, 400), 10)
     
     #SQUARE
    square.draw()

    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 10
    square = Square()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        #JUMPING
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if not jump and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    jump = True

        if jump:
            jump, jumpCount = square.jump(jumpCount)

        draw_window(square)

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Output:

[image: This is output]